# Perl syntax and readibility -- finding elements in array reference

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

This question concerns readability and good practice in Perl. I have a few checks I make:

- If I have the variable $array_ref, I just need to know if that array has at least one element equal to the text 'match'. It is possible that $array_ref is undefined or, if $array_ref is defined, then the array it references is empty (or even undefined? Is that possible?)
- I check if a scalar equals 1
- I check if another scalar equals 'yes'

Here is the current code I am using:

```
 my $is_compatible = $array_ref and defined grep $_ eq 'match', @{$array_ref}
                     and $my_num = 1 and $my_text eq 'yes'.
```

Can this be fixed up to be more easily changeable and readable? Also, does it fit all the possible use cases of what the value of $array_ref could be?

Comment: Your current code generates a warning `Useless use of string eq in void context` (if you have warnings enabled as you should) because you have a precedence error.  The low precedence `and` is designed for flow control; here you should use `&&`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start by not using `and`. You want to stick to a symbolic operators for the visual cue it gives. Named operators are usually found where terms are found, and `and` and `or` are usually used for flow control. Both of those hints are wrong here, so you don't want to give those hints.

The following arrangement is quite easy to read. The proof is that it became blindingly obvious that you used `=` where you should have used `==`.

```
my $is_compatible = ( $array && grep $_ eq 'match', @$array )
    && $my_num == 1
    && $my_text eq 'yes';
```

If you wanted to use a sub, the following would suffice.

```
sub is_compatible {
   my ($array, $my_num, $my_text) = @_;
   return 0 if !$array || !grep $_ eq 'match', @$array;
   return 0 if $my_num != 1;
   return 0 if $my_text ne 'yes';
   return 1;
}
```

Both of these approaches make similar things look similar and different things look different, allowing extremely efficient code scanning.

Answer (score 3):

```
sub is_compatible {
   my $array_ref = shift;
   defined( $array_ref )
       or return;
   ref $array_ref eq ref []
       or return;
   return unless grep $_ eq 'match', @$array_ref;

   my $my_num = shift;
   $my_num == 1
       or return;

   my $my_text = shift;
   $my_text eq 'yes'
       or return;

   return 1;
}
```

Comment: I am partial to the format I stole off of brian d foy: `ref $array_ref eq ref []`

Comment: Isn't it confusing to have `shift` statements all over the sub? I feel it is a lot easier to grok the meaning of a subroutine if all the arguments can be seen at the top.